# Salesforce formula Logic

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am attempting to write a formula that will calculate an amount but if the serviceFee field has a value it will use that value.

So

```
Field1 = Amount
Field2 = ServiceFee
```

If ServiceFee has a value the amount must equal the servicefee
If any of the ClientTypes are matched the formula will not look at the ServiceFee

I have tried deploying this but the formula seems to execure the ServiceFee section only

```
IF(ClientType.Id = '123456', 
   Amount- Discount, 
   IF(ClientType.Id = '7891011', 
      Amount + 1,
      IF(NOT(ISBLANK(ServiceFee)), 
         Amount = ServiceFee, 
      )
   )
)
```

Comment: This formula is not valid and won't compile. Could you please include the formula you are currently using, verbatim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to assign `Amount` a value in the last statement, which doesn't work in formula syntax. It won't compile because that is actually parsed as a comparison statement (returning a boolean value).

Instead, first determine what the formula should return. If you have several Client Ids, try the `CASE` function. That way it's clear what happens in each of the scenarios. For example:

```
CASE(ClientType.Id,
  '123456',  Amount - Discount,
  '7891011', Amount + 1,
  IF(ISBLANK(ServiceFee), 0, ServiceFee)
)
```

The last argument is the default of the `CASE` function and will be evaluated if `ClientType.Id` isn't either of the previous values.